# how to implement event emitters rather than refreshing the page?

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

There is a component in my Website-Project called authorize-Product. As the title says its a component where product have to be authorized before displaying in the shop component. I have implemented a list with these items with a "accept" or "reject" button. Everything works but I have to refresh the page after every klick on one of these 2 button so this item isn't shown anymore. I heard about EventEmitters which are a better way than refreshing the page every time but I didn't understand how to implement it. Can someone help?

this is my authorize.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-authorization',
  templateUrl: './product-authorization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-authorization.component.css']
})
export class ProductAuthorizationComponent implements OnInit {

  isAdmin: boolean;

  products: Product[];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'location', 'delivarable', 'description', 'price', 'acceptorreject'];


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getProducts()
  }

  getProducts(){
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.endpointURL + 'products/authorized/no').subscribe((res: any) =>
    {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res;
    })
  }

  authorizeProduct(product: Product){
    product.authorized = "yes"
    product.status = "available"


    return this.httpClient.put(environment.endpointURL + 'products/' + product.productId, product ).subscribe((res: any) =>
    {
      console.log("Update:");
      console.log(res);

      //refresh page to update table
      this.refresh()
    })

  }

  rejectProduct(productId: number){
    return this.httpClient.delete(environment.endpointURL + 'products/' + productId).subscribe((res: any) =>
    {
      console.log("Delete:");

      //refresh page to update table
      this.refresh()
    })
  }

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

}
```

and this is my authorize.html file which shows the list:

```
<h3>Products to be authorized:</h3>

<table
mat-table [dataSource]="products" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="delivarable">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delivarable </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.delivarable}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="acceptorreject">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Authorize </th>
    <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="authorizeProduct(element)">Accept</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="rejectProduct(element.productId)">Reject</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an `@output` decorator. Here are the relavent [docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#how-to-use-output).

Basically you will make a property that looks something like this:

```
// remember to import Output and EventEmitter from @angular/core

@Output() authorize = new EventEmitter();

// To emit the event update your authorizeProduct method
authorizeProduct(product: Product){
  product.authorized = "yes"
  product.status = "available"

  return this.httpClient.put(environment.endpointURL + 'products/' + product.productId, product ).subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log("Update:");
    console.log(res);

    //refresh page to update table
    this.authorize.emit()
  })
}
```

Then in your parent component you can watch the event like this

```
<app-product-authorization (authorize)="someFunctionInYourComponent()"></app-product-authorization>
```

Comment: So the idea is that it doesn't show the products anymore which are accepted oder rejected. With the klick the Product isn't in the 'getProducts' method anymore bc the link changes. The routing to this component is shown in my 'home component' which looks like this:`<nav class = "topnav" mat-tab-nav-bar> <a *ngIf="isAdmin==true"
     class="link" id="authorize" mat-tab-link
     routerLink="Authorize"
     routerLinkActive
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
     #rla3="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla3.isActive">Authorize</a>` what is meant by "someFunctionInYourComponent"